# Installing Boost 1.48 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, boost

Ubuntu 12.04 has two libboost-dev packages. The default is 1.46, but there is also a 1.48. I have updated libboost-all-dev to 1.48 without any errors.

[image]

I was expecting that all previous links to boost 1.46 be replaced by the newer version. But they are still in place:

[image]

One of my libraries needs version 1.48. It looks into /usr/lib but since the symbolic links are all referring to the old boost, gives me an error. There are so many symbolic links. Is there any way to update them all? Is there any better solution since changing the links might break some other libraries that are relying on the older version of boost.

Comment: Have you checked /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu (or i386-linux-gnu)?

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the output of `dpkg -l | grep boost` so we can see the versions of all your Boost packages? Please paste it as text and not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

This should be on [AskUbuntu.SE] or [SU] likely.

Anyways, to see what gets linked, do a `ldd` on your program

```
ldd a.out
```

To see where the libraries belonging to a package ended up:

```
dpkg --listfiles libboost-filesystem1.48.0
```

To find out which package owns the file you see:

```
dpkg --search /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.48.0
```